# How to randomize an array json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, random

How to randomize an array json in php

**JSON PART**:

file.json

```
[
    {
        "Country":"Germany",
        "male":["Andrew","Michael","John"],
        "female":["Emily","Hannah", "Mia"],
        "id":["1","2","3"]
    }
]
```

**PHP PART:**

```
$f = file_get_contents("file.json");
$file = json_decode($f, true);

$gm = $file["male"];
$male = $gm[rand(0, count($gm) - 1)];

$gf = $file["female"];
$female = $gf[rand(0, count($gf) - 1)];

echo 'male'. $gm. 'female'. $gf;
```

i don't know the problem :(

Comment: [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) provides a neater way of doing what you're doing with rand and count. (Not related to your problem, just FYI.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this：

```
$f = file_get_contents("file.json");
$file = json_decode($f, true);
$gm = $file[0]["male"];// this is key
$male = $gm[rand(0, count($gm) - 1)];

$gf = $file[0]["female"];
$female = $gf[rand(0, count($gf) - 1)];

echo 'male:'. $male. '--female:'. $female;// notice variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your randomisation will work correctly -- the problem is that you're **outputting** the wrong variables; you're outputting the entire arrays rather than a random value from them.

Instead of `$gm` and `$gf`, you want to output `$male` and `$female`:

```
echo 'male'. $male. 'female'. $female;
```